# Is attr_accessor the issue with this contact form in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, attr-accessor

First off, i know attr_accessible is deprecated in Rails 4, but what about attr_accessor?

When you hit submit it's returning a "Template is Missing" error, but that's because its hitting an error somewhere in the send proccess then just trying to return "connect#create" which doesn't exist as a physical page.

When i check the log files, I am getting a 500 internal server error when trying to send a contact form, and I'm not sure if using attr_accessor in Rails 4 is the culprit. Is there a newer way to write this?

```
class Message

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone, :subject, :company, :title, :market, :body

  validates :name, :email, :subject, :company, :body, :presence => true
  validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

The above is the message model for the contact form:

Is it something within the process of sending the data?

The rest of the code for the contact mail functionality is:

**Contact Mailer**

```
class ContactMailer< ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "noreply@test.com"
  default :to => "{{MY EMAIL}}"

  def new_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail(:subject => "Test Message")
  end

end
```

In /views/contact_mailer/ there is a new_message.text.erb file:

```
Name: <%= @message.name %>

Email: <%= @message.email %>

Phone: <%= @message.phone %>

Subject: <%= @message.subject %>

Company: <%= @message.company %>

Title: <%= @message.title %>

Market: <%= @message.market %>

Body: <%= @message.body %>
```

My Routes are:

```
match 'connect' => 'connect#index', :as => 'connect', :via => :get
match 'connect' => 'connect#create', :as => 'connectpost', :via => :post
```

The connect page controller:

```
class ConnectController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(connect_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

And finally....the SMTP settings in /config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port => 587,
:domain => "{{SITE DOMAIN}}",
:user_name => "{{GMAIL EMAIL}}",
:password => "{{GMAIL EMAIL PASSWORD}}",
:authentication => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: It's not attr_accessor - I'll bet it's your mailer.

Comment out the line in ConnectController#create where you send the mail then try again?

If it does the same, the issue might be with your validations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My ConnectController#Create was trying to initialize

```
NotificationMailers.new_message()
```

But it needed to be:

```
ContactMailer.new_message()
```

I have no idea why the tutorial I followed would have the wrong class name there...but that was the issue.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessor`, `attr_writer` and `attr_reader` are all part of vanilla core Ruby and are helper methods for [Modules](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) and Classes.

They work fine in Ruby 2.0, so you'll have to mark them off your suspect list.